# My canvas tag won't display data unless I add a 2nd reference to its controller as an attribute?

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent `div` which sets a reference to my controller, `DataCtrl`.  Then I have an `ng-repeat`, followed by a canvas tag.  The canvas tag is clearly a child element of the `DataCtrl`, and yet none of the data from it is displayed unless I give it it's own `ng-controller="DataCtrl"` attribute.  I know this must not be right as that calls the DataCtrl constructor for every graph!

```
<!--First Reference to Data Ctrl -->

<div class="data-visual" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  <div id="status" ng-if="isLoggedIn()" ng-repeat="data in unit.all_data">

    <!--Graph only displays data if I once again add a reference to DataCtrl-->
    <!--Otherwise it's completely blank!-->

    <div ng-controller='DataCtrl'>
        <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data[$index]" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `unit.all_data` is an array may be use

```
<canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
```

without using `$index`